# Can't open bz2-compressed (with python) file with normal archive manager

Tags: python, compression, bzip2

I've written some code to bz2-compress a file with the BZ2 Compressor Object:

```
def compressFile(file_name, new_name):      
    comp = bz2.BZ2Compressor()
    comFile = open(new_name, "wb")
    oldFile = open(file_name, "rb")
    while True:
        data = oldFile.read(1024*1024)
        if(len(data) == 0):
            break
        compressed = comp.compress(data)
        comFile.write(compressed)
    comp.flush()
    comFile.close()
```

I don't get an error and the file is created, but when I want to open it with an archive manager, I get a nonspecific error. I can't find my mistake and this module is poorly documented.

Comment: "While extracting files, an error has occurred."

Comment: Do you actually have bzip installed? Does it work from the command line?

Comment: Here I get an Error: `bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
 perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: No such file or directory
 Input file = brownies-fuer-nerds.pdf.bz2, output file = brownies-fuer-nerds.pdf

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.`
The -tvv says: `[1: huff+mtf rt+rld]
    [2: huff+mtf file ends unexpectedly`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a `BZ2Compressor`, you get data in chunks when you call `compress()`, and a good chance is that you only get the data when you call `flush()`.

It should work if you change your function like this:

```
def compressFile(file_name, new_name):      
    comp = bz2.BZ2Compressor()
    comFile = open(new_name, "wb")
    oldFile = open(file_name, "rb")
    while True:
        data = oldFile.read(1024*1024)
        if(len(data) == 0):
            break
        comFile.write(comp.compress(data))
    comFile.write(comp.flush())
    comFile.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, here you get `ValueError: this object was already flushed`